# CSS Fixed Position Padding Effect

Tags: html, css

I know that if you have a normal positioned div, such that you don't define `position:whatever`, you have to respect the box model:

```
.css-class {
    width:280px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

The width of this `div` would be `300px`.

However, if you set `position:fixed` I've noticed that the `padding` property doesn't get added onto the overall width property.

Is this a true case, or is there something else going on here?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq4Sg/) I'm working on

Comment: I don't understand your question, here both divs have the same width : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3GLn4/

Comment: Or you could just use `box-sizing:border-box` and have done with it.

Comment: I'm wondering whether this is normal behaviour, or is there something else at work!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. But as far as I know using fixed positioning doesn't remove the padding.

Comment: Its not about getting removed, in the scenario the div becomes `300px` because of padding being added, however, in the `fixed` scenario the padding doesn't get added so the overall `width` stays at the `width` specified!